# Java - Load Balancing Task Queues

Tags: java, load-balancing, message-queue, distribution, task-queue

Assume that we have some task queues and we use **Weighted Task Distribution Scheme** to distribute tasks across them.

[image]

after a while, it could be like this :

[image]

Weights are **approximate**. for example, in a bank application we may assign

- **W1** to **Withdrawal** Service (or Task)
- **W2** to **Deposit** Service
- **W3** to **Transfer** Service

etc. But for some reasons, A task may take longer (or less) than expected, which may disrupt the balance between queues.

[image]

In the Application level, with the following pseudocode in mind :

```
public class Actor implements Runnable {

    BlockingQueue<Task> mailbox = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    AtomicInteger load = new AtomicInteger();

    void tell(Task task) {
        if (mailbox.offer(task)) {
            load.getAndAdd(task.weight);
        }
    }

    int load() {
        return load.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        setState(ACTIVE);
        try {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                Task task;
                if ((task = mailbox.poll()) == null) {
                    setState(IDLE);
                    if ((task = mailbox.poll(IDLE_TIMEOUT)) == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    setState(ACTIVE);
                }
                load.getAndAdd(-task.weight);
                handle(task);
            }
        } finally {
            setState(IN_ACTIVE);
        }
    }

}
```

There's 3 main questions :

1. Do we really need to load balance?
   if yes, then
2. When? (using `Timer` or...)
3. and How?

Comment: you did not tell about the important factor - what is the average distribution for different task types?

Comment: I don't know. It is completely random. However, it can be calculated later during the execution of the program.